# paths directory abbreviation is ignored in tsconfig

Tags: node.js, typescript, sveltekit, ts-node

I have a file at location `src/lib/db.ts` and a script `script.ts` that imports the `db` file using `import ... from "$lib/db"`. My `tsconfig.json` contains

```
"paths": {
            "$lib": [
                "src/lib"
            ],
            "$lib/*": [
                "src/lib/*"
            ]
        },
```

It was set-up by SvelteKit. But when I do

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm script.ts --project tsconfig.json
```

I get

```
/home/..../node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:757
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base));
        ^
CustomError: Cannot find package '$lib' imported from script.ts.
```

Comment: Is that command line even valid? It looks like that would pass `--project tsconfig.json` to the script, rather than to `ts-node`.

Comment: @H.B. yes the command is valid. I have heard there are problems with esm, ts-node and path aliases. Is this related?

Comment: @H.B. I found this but it seems risky to use https://github.com/luanglopes/ts-paths-esm-loader

Comment: For SvelteKit you should not need anything else, it takes care of registering the aliases in Vite. Why are you trying to execute a script manually?

Comment: @H.B. I need to run a script externally from outside svelte. I don't know how to use the aliases without vite.

Comment: Depending on what the script contains that will lead no-where, even if you get the alias to work, because if you try to reference Svelte files in that script, a regular TS or JS runtime will not be able to do anything with them.

Comment: @H.B. I am not referencing any svelte things in the files. I have learned to use typescript through sveltekit, but I would like to find a way to have code in my endpoints run through external scripts and processes without rewriting all imports.

Comment: You can always compile the TS down to JS first, if things like `ts-node` cannot resolve the imports directly.